# Use Powershell to find a file by its version data

Tags: powershell

I am looking for a specific version of a file, which our build process outputs. I'm looking for a file which has both `File Version` and `Product version` set to a specific value in the format `x.x.x.x`

I can't seem to find a PowerShell command/parameter to pass in which will allow me to specify either of these attributes.

Comment: Try `gci * -file | select -exp versioninfo`

Comment: `gci | where { $_.VersionInfo.FileVersion -eq 'x.x.x.x' -and $_.VersionInfo.FileVersion -eq 'x.x.x.x' }`

Comment: @Balthazar pretty sure that is not going to work. Either -eq is -le and -ge or its -or. On second thought, I think the second is not .FileVersion but .ProductVersion

Comment: `gci | where { $_.VersionInfo.FileVersion -eq 'x.x.x.x' }` got me what I was looking for, thank you. I just need to make it search recursively over a drive now.

Comment: `gci -recurse | ...`

Comment: @LPChip oops, yes the second one should have been ProductVersion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achieved this by running the following in PowerShell

`gci -recurse | where { $_.VersionInfo.FileVersion -eq 'x.x.x.x' }`

This returned me a list of files with the expected version.

Kudos to @lieven & @belthazar for the tips.